# How come when I try to compile my C program by making a file named for the program it creates an application for it?

Tags: c, gcc

I once tried to compile a C program I made that was for a chess game (thanks to YouTube's Bluefever Software for the tutorial), but when I went to compile the program, I executed this line of code:

```
C:\TDM-GCC-64\>gcc Chess/chess.c Chess/init.c -o chess
```

The compiling worked (there were no syntax errors or anything), but when I got to my file directory, I saw this (circled in blue):

An unexpected application (but there were no viruses!):

[image]

How did this happen? It may had something to do with the line I was compiling, but what is the "intel" behind this?

Comment: Your AV system recognized that a new executable had been created (your `chess`, or `chess.exe`, program), and also checked it as virus-free.  I would want to see the file name suffixes in the output — it's an option you can set.

Comment: What did you expect ?

Comment: Did you type the posted command or `gcc Chess/chess.c Chess/init.c -o Chess/chess`?

Comment: I typed the posted command.

Comment: Is there a file named `chess.exe` in the parent directory?

Comment: Actually, yes, there is a file named `chess.exe` in `C:\TDM-GCC-64`!

Comment: Well, that's your executable file produced by `gcc`.  the file names `chess.exe` in the `Chess` directory is an older one, maybe imported from the project or compiled earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is normal for the compiler to generate an application!

What is surprising is the location for the executable, it should have been generated in the parent directory:

```
 C:\TDM-GCC-64\> gcc Chess/chess.c Chess/init.c -o chess
```

The explanation is interesting:

- You are using the Windows operating system, where the filenames are case insensitive.
- You instructed gcc to generate the executable into `chess`, but this is the name of the `Chess` directory.  In this case, gcc generates the executable in the named directory and gives it a name that is the basename of the first source file `chess.c` -> `chess`.
- Furthermore, the application name really is `chess.exe` in Windows, but the default setting for the file manager is to not display file extensions.  This is a very unfortunate choice.  I suggest you change this setting in the Windows/File Explorer Options window to always show file extensions.  This will allow you to distinguish `chess.c`, `chess.exe` and `chess.h` more easily.

You have a `Makefile` in the Chess directory, you should use the `make` command to build the executable:

```
 C:\TDM-GCC-64\> make -C Chess
```

Or simply `cd` to the `Chess` subdirectory and type:

```
 C:\TDM-GCC-64\Chess> make
```

Comment: But, when I execute the `make` command it throws an error saying that `'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue:  You might want to install `cygwin`.  It has a lot of useful tools for C development in Windows.

Comment: I actually already have `cygwin.h`, I think I just need to include it in order for the `make` command to work.

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue: no, changing your source code will not magically make the Wndows shell find the `make` command.  This is a `PATH` issue or a setup issue. You should run the `cygwin` batch or command file to start the bash shell in a window, and run commands there.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I do that?

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue: It is logical: when you type `make` in the shell window, CMD.EXE does not find it and reports the error `'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`,  you cannot fix that by changing your source files, you have to change the PATH variable to include the cygwin binary directory or prefereably use the cygwin shell directly.

Comment: In the Control Panel? Isn't it in Windows Explorer/File Explorer itself, menu *View* → "Options" → tab "View", uncheck *Uncheck extensions for known file types*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: You are probably correct, the configuration settings for the File Explorer belong there. I have not used Windows for a long time and this setting used to be in an unexpected place.

Answer (score 3):

That's the file you told the compiler to make.

The `-o` option to gcc is the output file.  In this case, you told it to create an executable file named `chess`.  And that's exactly what was created.

Comment: Yes, but why it the executable generated in the `Chess` subdirectory?

Comment: Are you sure it is ? The timestamp on that file looks older than the other files. Perhaps you ran make in that directory once, or otherwise created the file there earlier.

Comment: @nos: I am not sure where it is created.  It might be created in the parent directory as `chess.exe`, and the `chess.exe` in the `Chess` directory is an older executable, possibly generated by `make`.

Comment: It was created in the `TDM-GCC-64` directory, but I moved it into the `Chess` subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is automatically creating an executable file while compiling.